# Chrome keeps opening new tabs as new windows

Tags: google-chrome

I have an issue of new tabs being opened as new windows.

If I click the new tab button (beside existing tab), or right click and open in new tab, it briefly opens a new tab, but then switches to a new window.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I've searched trough the settings for chrome, and can't find anything that would allow that. The odd thing is my chrome opens all links in new tab by default. A quick google search reveals that addons MAY cause this issue. Do you have any addon in chrome that may affect this behavior?

Comment: Yeah, I've solved this, there was a add on that was specifically doiing it.. 

I have a malware on my other computer that's adding adware chrome extensions, I've been unable to remove it. 

Because my computers are synced via google accounts, it keeps adding the same extensions to both computers. What a pain.

Comment: 21/11/2020 solved it. go to https://www.google.com/preferences, look for where results open and untick the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

There was a chrome extension called 'New tab, New Window' that was causing it.

The extension is installed by a malware.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you do not have sticky keys on, that may cause a problem. Shift-clicking a link in Chrome opens a new window.

Press shift more than five times rapidly to find out if sticky keys are on.  Another clue is if your text is always capitalized and numbers come out as symbols.

Comment: It looks like *you* have sticky keys on. Or maybe just good old caps lock.

Answer (score 0):

It was sticky keys here. I ran the back of my hand over all the keys on the keyboard and then it stopped doing it.

Comment: I think is a different kind of [Sticky Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_keys)...

Answer (score 0):

No malware on my laptop, but all links I clicked were opening in a new window. After clearing the browser cache that behavior stopped.

Click on the Chrome menu > Select Clear browsing data... > Under cached images and files, select All time (next to time-range)> Click the Clear Data button at the bottom.

Answer (score -2):

open your chrome browser and type in url address bar www.google.com and type any randam website that you know like amazon.com and search then click left hand side setting bar and go on search setting then see there ......
( Where results open

Open each selected result in a new browser window.)
u have to uncheck the box and then click on save and close your chrome ur browser then restart ............ 
if it is not working then you have to restore your chrome setting

Comment: What do you mean by "click left hand side setting bar"?